# Не могу получить атрибуты файла

Tags: файлы, swift, атрибуты

Не могу получить атрибуты файла. Файл находится по этому пути:

> .../Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/0BEA4792-3788-49BF-A56E-15DB72ECFB13/data/Containers/Data/Application/14E8207D-681C-4D0C-9AB4-F708493A276D/Documents/lifLog.txt

Путь правильный, файл лежит именно там.

Функция

```
private class func getDateOfCreatingLog()
{
    let dir = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.AllDomainsMask, true).first
    let path = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: dir!).URLByAppendingPathComponent(logName)
    let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
    
    do
    {
        let attributes = try fileManager.attributesOfItemAtPath(path.absoluteString)
        
        print(attributes)
    }
    catch {print("Cannot get attributes of log")}
}
```

Comment: А сам файл видите? Что не так-то? Не можете получить аттрибуты, а что Вы получаете вообще в принципе? Уточните вопрос.

Comment: @DenisBubnov сам файл вижу, могу записать/прочитать. Мне нужно получить дату создания и размер файла

Comment: Вот так пробовали: `let fileSize = attributes[NSFileSize]` и `let creationDate = attributes[NSFileCreationDate];`? Какой версии *Swift* у Вас используется, 2 или 3?

Comment: @DenisBubnov не получается - попадает сразу при создании attributes  в блок catch. Swift 2

Comment: Ну вот это другое дело. Что в исключении написано?

Comment: @DenisBubnov ничего, кроме моего принта

Comment: В блоке `catch` напишите следующий код: `let nsError = error as NSError; print(nsError.localizedDescription)` и скажите, что получили. Или вот так: `catch let error as NSError { print("Failed: \(error.localizedDescription)") }`. Нужен текст ошибки, чтобы узнать, что не так.

Comment: @DenisBubnov пишет что не может найти этот файл, хотя по пути на который он ругается, файл лежит. Может дело в path.absoluteString?